# Prevent remounting of expensive (class) component with shouldComponentUpdate() (List of images, inside router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, react-hooks

I'm rendering a very large list of images that, when clicked individually, are added to a "viewer" div.  The problem is that each time I add an image to the viewer, the original list re-renders, even though no changes have been made to the list's content.

I've tried using `shouldComponentUpdate()` at every level, as well as using `React.memo`.  Neither appear to have any effect.  I've also looked in to whether the time should be spent making the components functional and researching hooks (`useContext()` looks enticing), but I'm too new at React to know if that would just be more time wasted. (Please feel free weigh in on whether this is a waste of time.)

I don't know where the problem is, so I'm not sure a snippet would do much good. Instead, I've stripped down the problem to its bones and posted a sandbox version here

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-darkness-l920b

At the moment, my `shouldComponentUpdate` comparison is pretty straightforward for each class; something like:

```
if (nextProps.photoData === this.props.photoData) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

If you open the codesandbox console you'll see I'm logging `Year.js > <ImageList /> is rendering` to flag each successive render of the list in question.

Any help, even a nudge in the right direction, would be hugely appreciated.  I've been reading blog articles for a solid day now and nothing seems to help.

Comment: Functional components and hooks are the way to move forward with how react is progressing. Give it a shot to learn and understand what issues hooks solves.

Comment: If you can use redux, 1) have your image list data in it, and render your image list by fetching data from it. 2) Create a method which on image click updates the viwer list data in redux 3) render your viewer list by fetching data from redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `PhotoView` in `App.js` is defined inside render method, so when  state update causing the render, then the `PhotoView` redefined again. It's a new component every time for The App component.

Please define components outside the render function:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Year from "./Year";
import Viewer from "./Viewer";
import dataObj from "./dataObj.json";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.PhotoView = this.PhotoView.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      current: {
        year: 2019,
        url: ""
      },
      viewerData: [],
      photoData: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      photoData: dataObj
    });
  }

  addToViewer = moment =>
    this.setState(state => {
      const viewerData = state.viewerData.concat(moment.props.data);
      return {
        viewerData,
        value: ""
      };
    });
  About() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>About</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };
  PhotoView(url) {
      return (
        <div className="PhotoView">
          <Year
            setCurrent={this.setCurrent}
            photoData={this.state.photoData}
            addToViewer={this.addToViewer}
          />
          <Viewer
            viewerData={this.state.viewerData}
            setCurrent={this.setCurrent}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <nav>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            <Link to="/">Photo View</Link>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/about" exact component={this.About} />
            <Route path="/" component={this.PhotoView} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Or move them to individual files.

Comment: Thank you @AppleJam ! I was definitely barking up the wrong tree on this.